# Can't get reflect to not return pointers, compiler panics on conversion?

Tags: pointers, reflection, go, interface

Code written around something like this is causing an issue:

```
func CreateNewItemOfType(returnType reflect.Type) (interface {}) {
    return reflect.New(returnType).Interface();

}
```

... How can one actually return a struct of `returnType` and not a pointer to a struct, as `reflect` creates here? The compiler builds this fine but panics at run-time, yet will not accept an asterisk in front of the return call here in order to actually return the struct and not a pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`reflect.New()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#New) creates a new value of the specified type, and returns the [`reflect.Value`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value) descriptor of a *pointer* to that value. You may use [`Value.Elem()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Elem) to "navigate" from pointer to pointed value wrapped in a `reflect.Value`. Then you can call [`Value.Interface()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Interface) to get the value (struct) as an `interface{}` value.

If you need a value of concrete type, you may use [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) to "extract" the value wrapped in the `interface{}` value.

```
func CreateNewItemOfType(returnType reflect.Type) interface{} {
    return reflect.New(returnType).Elem().Interface()
}
```

Testing it:

```
type Point struct {
    X, Y int
}

t := reflect.TypeOf(Point{})

i := CreateNewItemOfType(t) // i is of type interface{}
fmt.Printf("%T %+v\n", i, i)

pt := i.(Point) // pt is of type Point
fmt.Printf("%T %+v\n", pt, pt)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ApIG-VgS6q)):

```
main.Point {X:0 Y:0}
main.Point {X:0 Y:0}
```

**Note:**

It is also possible to obtain the non-pointer struct value if `Value.Elem()` is not used. For that, you need to type-assert the pointer value (of type `*Point`), then you can dereference the pointer to get the non-pointer.

See this example:

```
t := reflect.TypeOf(Point{})
pi := reflect.New(t).Interface() // pi is of type interface{}
fmt.Printf("%T %+v\n", pi, pi)

ppt := pi.(*Point) // pt is of type *Point
fmt.Printf("%T %+v\n", ppt, ppt)

i2 := *ppt // i2 is of type Point
fmt.Printf("%T %+v\n", i2, i2)
```

Output:

```
*main.Point &{X:0 Y:0}
*main.Point &{X:0 Y:0}
main.Point {X:0 Y:0}
```

Comment: @BenGuild Yes, but you can call `Value.Interface()` on the `Value` returned by `Value.Elem()`. It's in the answer, read it.

Comment: @icza If I do that, then it's a pointer and if I try to "type assert" it... it says it's a pointer of that type not the type itself, and we're back to my original question.

Comment: @BenGuild Did you try the examples I included in the answer? Click on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ApIG-VgS6q) link to try them. Output is posted as verification.

Comment: @icza Those work in that example, but I'm getting things like "panic: reflect.Value.Addr of unaddressable value" when I try to cast these back to pointers for later use.

Comment: @BenGuild Then you should post more of your code so that we can tell what's wrong with it.

Comment: The problem is that if I call `CreateNewItemOfType(returnType)` as shown above, then try to take the result of that and pass it as like an `&out` parameter to another function... it panics with that.

Comment: However, if I do `reflect.New(returnType).Interface()` without `Elem()` in between, it works fine ... yet returns a pointer and I can't type assert that to its actual type (returnType)... only to a pointer of the returnType. As mentioned in my original question, the compiler panics if I try to turn it from a pointer to a non-pointer, because it thinks it's an interface not a pointer. It will only let me type assert it to a pointer version of that type at runtime, which I can't use consistently.

Comment: @BenGuild Please, show your exact code so that we can help you.

Comment: OK, please give me a minute.

Comment: I've been struggling to come up with a generic example but I've been unsuccessful so far. I'll post one but it involves a third-party library that is balking at types:

Comment: (returnType is passed a custom struct's type:) `structOfReturnType := reflect.New(returnType).Elem().Interface(); err=db.Where("user=?", 1).First(structOfReturnType).Error;` ... This throws "panic: reflect.Value.Addr of unaddressable value" and involves the `GORM` library https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/issues/394 ........ If I omit the `Elem()` call as mentioned above, it works fine but then it's a pointer and the compiler fails when trying to cast it with an asterisk ( invalid indirect ).

Comment: Oh, I forgot the "&" in front of `structOfReturnType` in that, sorry. I think the issue here now is that I have to type assert this as well.

Comment: OK, I've been able to rejigger this a bit with the help of your code. Where I was hitting a snag was trying to pass a pointer myself through an `interface {}` typed variable to *another* function... then there's no way to asterisk that back there without the compiler throwing a panic. Is there a way around that?

Comment: @BenGuild Yes, there is. `Value.Elem()` as described. If `i` is of type `interface{}` which holds a pointer, then `reflect.ValueOf(i).Elem().Interface()`.

Comment: I'm going to fork this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37504458/issue-translating-data-back-from-serialization-into-go-struct-dynamically-using ...