# Issue translating data back from serialization into Go struct dynamically using reflection

Tags: google-app-engine, pointers, reflection, go, interface

I'm having trouble using reflection in Go to fetch data from a cache dynamically into various statically declared struct types:

```
func FetchFromCacheOrSomewhereElse(cacheKey string, returnType reflect.Type) (out interface {}, err error) {
    fetchFromCache := reflect.New(returnType).Interface();
    _, err=memcache.Gob.Get(*context, cacheKey, &fetchFromCache);

    if (err==nil) {
        out=reflect.ValueOf(fetchFromCache).Elem().Interface();

    } else if (err==memcache.ErrCacheMiss) {
        /* Fetch data manually... */

    }

    return out, err;

}
```

It seems that `reflect` won't translate this statically typed cache data back into a reflect value, and returns this error instead: `gob: local interface type *interface {} can only be decoded from remote interface type; received concrete type` ... :\

This data is saved elsewhere in the code to the cache without the need for `reflect`.

Comment: Try this: `memcache.Gob.Get(*context, cacheKey, fetchFromCache)` (note no address `&` operator before `fetchFromCache`).

Comment: Wow, *facepalm*. After spending all day on this, with your help, I'm finally able to nearly get it right on my own. Ha, thank you.

Comment: Quick follow-up question: For some reason, this isn't returning `true` in the above code ... `(err==memcache.ErrCacheMiss)` ... yet this is `true`: `(err!=nil && err.Error()==memcache.ErrCacheMiss.Error())` .... I'd prefer to avoid string comparison, is there a fix for this?

Comment: You should never do string comparison on errors. I find it unlikely what you wrote,  please double check. But do this: first check if `err != nil && err != memcache.ErrCacheMiss` and if so, return early. Also if it's `memcache.ErrCacheMiss` and you manually fetch data successfully, you should return a `nil` error by setting `err` to `nil`. Maybe your confusion comes from you still returning the `memcache.ErrCacheMiss` in this case.

Comment: Yeah, it seemed a bit odd that the errors weren't matching but the strings were. I'm going to flush my `pkg` directory and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`memcache.Gob.Get()` which is [`Codec.Get()`](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/appengine/memcache#Codec.Get) expects the "target" as a pointer, wrapped into an `interface{}`.

Your `fetchFromCache` is already just that: a pointer to a value of the specified type (`returnType`) wrapped in an `interface{}`. So you don't need to take its address when passing it to `Gob.Get()`: pass it as-is:

```
_, err=memcache.Gob.Get(*context, cacheKey, fetchFromCache)
```